# str method not printing correctly

Tags: python, string

I'm working on creating a subclass Rug from a parent class rectangle for school.
Everything looks like it should be working but when I try to print the `__str__` method for the subclass the only that populates from the parent class is `<__main__.Rug object at 0x0000019C2B69C400>`.

This is my Parent Class :

```py
import math

class Rectangle:
    
    def __init__(self, l, w):
        self.setLength(l)
        self.setWidth(w)
        
    def getLength(self):
        return self.__length

    def setLength(self, l):
        if l < 0:
            l = 1
        self.__length = l

    def getWidth(self):
        return self.__width

    def setWidth(self, w):
        if w < 0:
            w = 1
        self.__width = w

    def getArea(self):
        return self.__length * self.__width
```

This is my `Rug` subclass :

```py
class Rug(Rectangle):

    def __init__(self, l, w, p):
        super().__init__(l, w)
        self.__price = p

    def getPrice(self):
        return self.__price

    def __str__(self):
        return super().__str__() + ", Area: " + str(self.getArea()) + ", Price: " + str(self.getPrice())

def main ():
    r = Rug(float(input("Please enter length: ")), float(input("Please enter width: ")), 150)
    print(r)

main()
```

This is all in Python 3.

This is my first time asking a question on here so if I need to provide anymore information like the code for my `Rectangle` parent class please let me know.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The example you post can be different than your real code. In this case, you are asking for user input when creating `Rug`. For a test, use hard coded strings instead. Then post the output that you see. That makes it easier for us.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi - no, [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) _All non-keyword arguments are converted to strings like str() does_

Comment: @PranavHosangadi The print function still uses the value returned by `__str__()`.

Comment: We need to see what `Rectangle.__str__` does. The default `object.__str__` writes object like you show. If you don't like it, don't include `super().__str__()` in your call.

Comment: A few changes would help. (1) make a running program. We don't have `Rectangle` so can't run it. (2) post the output that you get. You say "<main.Rug object at 0x0000019C2B69C400>" but doesn't it include the extra stuff you add to it? (3) post what you want the output to look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is a `__str__(self)` implemented in the base class? If assuming your `Rectange` looks like the following:

```
class Rectangle():

    def __init__(self, l, w):
        self.length = l
        self.width = w

    def getArea(self):
        return self.length * self.width

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Rug {self.length}x{self.width}'
```

Your code would print the base function's string representation defined by it's `__str__()` function.

You could use f-string interpolation to clean up your `Rug.__str__()` as well:

```
class Rug(Rectangle):
    ...
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{super().__str__()}, Area: {self.getArea()}, Price: {self.getPrice()}'
```

Comment: I edited my org comment to add the parent class. My apologies on not having that on there. Do I have to have the __str__ on the parent class like yours and the subclass in order for it to print the correct output?